# How to host a SOAP web service WSDL in localhost?

Tags: soap, wsdl, localhost

I am a beginner programmer, and it's the first time to work with SOAP web services and WSDL files.

I am given a task to consume a SOAP web services provided by another company. However, we need to test internally first, then we consume from the service provider (hosted on their remote server).

**My question is. How to host this SOAP web service wsdl in localhost? As I have only the WSDL file.**

In the WSDL file, these are the locations. So I need to host the service locally so that I can test and get it work.

```
  <wsdl:service name="ABC_Out_AsycService">
      <wsdl:port name="HTTP_Port" binding="p1:ABC_Out_AsycBinding">
         <soap:address location="http://localhost" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
      </wsdl:port>
      <wsdl:port name="HTTPS_Port" binding="p1:ABC_Out_AsycBinding">
         <soap:address location="https://localhost" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [soapui](https://www.soapui.org/) for import and mock web services.

Basically, you [import the wsdl](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html) into the soapui and then [create a mock service](https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/service-mocking-overview.html). You could also import and create the mock in one step.

After this, you have a functional web service based on your wsdl that you can work with.

Comment: thanks a lot for your prompt response. I also asked the same question in Udemy the instructor answered me the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I spent a tone of time to find how to run soap locally having wsdl schema.